# Active menu from page id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, css, menu

I have gotten myself a little confused with this. I am trying to make my menus active based on the page id. At the moment I can pull the menus and display them but I am not able to make the current page active on the menu.

Here is my database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pagetitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `linklabel` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pagebody` text NOT NULL,
  `pageorder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `showing` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `descriptions` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `creationdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lastmodified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `extra` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Here is my menu display at the moment:

```
// Build Main Navigation menu and gather page data here
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id ASC";

$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

$menuDisplay = '';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $pid = $row["id"];

    $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];

    $menuDisplay .= '<ul><li><a href="index.php?pid='.$pid.'">'.$linklabel.'</a></li></ul>';
}

mysqli_free_result($query);
```

On the body of the page I just echo $menuDisplay like this

```
<div id="nav"><?php echo $menuDisplay ?></div><!--ends nav-->
```

I haven't done much on my css but here is the setup so far:

```
/*NAVIGATION*/

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

#nav li a:link, #nav li a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 12px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:active, #nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do something like this in your PHP:

```
// Build Main Navigation menu and gather page data here
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());
$menuDisplay = '<ul>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $pid = $row["id"];
  $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];
  $menuDisplay .= '<li' . ($pid == $_GET["pid"] ? ' class="selected"' : '') . '><a href="index.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $linklabel . '</a></li>';
}
mysqli_free_result($query);
$menuDisplay .= '</ul>';
```

This will add `class="selected"` to the `<li>` for the current page. Also, don't put each `<li>` in its own `<ul>`. I also fixed that.

Comment: thanks for the fix. I worked great. I used id instead of class and also defined a nav id for the ul 
`$menuDisplay = '<ul id="nav">';`

for the selected I used an id as well `  $menuDisplay .= '<li' . ($pid == $_GET["pid"] ? ' id="selected"' : '') . '><a href="index.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $linklabel . '</a></li>';`

I then defined in my css the menu look and feel. 
`#nav li {}`
`#nav li a:link, #nav li a:visited {}`
`#nav li a:hover {}`
`#nav li#selected {}`

It works great now. Thanks.